# _util.default.promisify is not a function using Node 9.5

Tags: javascript, webpack

**Node version:**

```
node -v
v9.5.0
```

**Code**

```
import util from 'util'
import fingerprint from 'fingerprint2'
const Fingerprint = util.promisify(fingerprint.get)
```

The error I'm getting in the browser is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _util.default.promisify is not a function
```

According to [the docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) it's supported. Any idea what is happening here?

I have also tried:

```
import { promisify } from 'util'
```

And

```
import util from 'util'
const { promisify } from util
```

... Same error.

Comment: the docs says `const util = require('util');` which is different from `import util from "util"` but equals to `import * as util from "util"`

Comment: Hang on a second. Is this because it's in the browser? Ha! I need to install the es6-promisify. I'm an idiot. But I did put "in the browser" in the question and everyone missed it.

Comment: Well Browser isn't NodeJS :)

Comment: @DanielKrom true, but in my defence I've been working on both backend and frontend code in JS today and as webpack, and npm, are a large part of my frontend workflow it's an easy mistake to make to include the wrong tag :)

Comment: @BugHunterUK my mistake

Comment: @NikitaIsaev it's ok, it was my mistake for tagging NodeJS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I managed to solve it. As this is a browser application it should have installed [es6-promisify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-promisify). Node's `promisify` will not work for obvious reasons. I should have realised that.

Comment: Lol, of cause we could have guessed it from the usage of Fingerprint, but it was kinda a key thing to mention for solving the issue :)

Comment: @NikitaIsaev erm if you read the question properly you would see that I said "The error I'm getting in the browser is" :p Thank you for your input though it was much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
import something from 'package';
```

is a shortand for

```
var something = require('package').default;
```

Use

```
import { promisify } from 'util';
```

instead.

Comment: I failed to mention that I already tried this. I also tried `import util from 'util'; const { promisify } = util` too. Exactly the same error.

Comment: Do what I described, then replace `util.promisify(fingerprint.get)` in your code with `promisify(fingerprint.get)`.

Comment: I've already tried all this before submitting the question. I have different branches using each 3 and all produce the same. See my question I edited with the things I've already tried.

Comment: @DanielKrom doesn't work for me, swear to God. I am the author of a very popular article on Node's promisfy and I have used this without problems in version 8.

Comment: Give up and try using the old syntax.

```const promisify = require('util').promisify;```

Comment: @BugHunterUK thats intresting (I accidentally deleted my comment) I'm gonna try it my self